# OPenFileDialog in win 7

Tags: c#

whats wrong with OpenFileDialog in win 7 ?
i used to do like this :

```
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();

        file.InitializeLifetimeService();

        file.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;

        file.ShowDialog();
```

but in win 7, programe goes to "not responding" state.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but in general, calling `ShowDialog` without passing the parent window is usually a bad idea: it simply uses the currently active window as the parent in that case which is not always what you want or expect.

Also, you never need to call `InitializeLifetimeService` manually: that is called for you automatically as part of the cross-domain marshalling stuff.

In addition, you should try breaking in to your program with a debugger and look at the state of the threads: what are the call stacks, what are the threads doing, etc.

Comment: i commented InitialLifetimeService but still nothing changed !
this work properly in Win Xp but in win 7 i goes to "Not Responding" state without any exception !